# Using delegation vs "property reverse scope"

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, ios7, delegates, delegation

I have a push segue from VC1 to VC2. In the prepare for segue going to VC2, I set a property of VC2 with the contents of a property in VC1 using the "=" operator.  I then changed the contents of that property IN VC2.  I now need to pass that property back to VC1.  I was under the impression that I could do this by delegation. However, it seems to "magically" change on it's own once I change it in VC2.  I really don't know the term for whatever this is is.  It must be the "=" operator assigning the same memory location to the property in VC1 and VC2, making both point to it right?  Please let me know the term for this and whether I should keep it like this or redo my model so I use delegation.

Thanks.

EDIT/Addition:

So this property1 in VC1 prepareForSegue, sets VC2's property1.  I then change property2 in VC2's textFieldDidEndEditing. When I run the program, property1 is statically allocated in VC1 fine.  I then check property1 in VC2 before it's changed, and it's fine, and then I check after it is modified and it's correctly modified.  However, when I go back to VC1(via back button in navigation controller), I check property1 of VC1 and it is the NEW modified version.  I thought I had to use delegation to pass it back to VC1.

My questions were, what is this called? some sort of scope or inheritance?  And should I have my program set up this way, or should I be forcing it to use delegation to get from the view to the model?

VC1.M

```
@interface VC1()
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *property1;
@end

@implementation VC1

@synthesize property1= _property1;
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"VC2_SEGUE"]){
        VC2 *mVC2 = (VC2 *)segue.destinationViewController;
        mVC2.property1 = self.property1;
    }
}

@end
```

VC2.H

```
@interface VC2: UITableViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
@property(nonatomic, strong)NSMutableDictionary *property1;
@end
```

VC2.M

```
@implementation VC2

@synthesize property1 = _property1;

-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    // Get the cell in which the textfield is embedded
    id textFieldSuper = textField;
    while (![textFieldSuper isKindOfClass:[CustomCel class]]) {
        textFieldSuper = [textFieldSuper superview];
    }
    // Get that cell's index path

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:(CustomCell   *)textFieldSuper];

    NSMutableArray *newObject = [[self.property1 objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", indexPath.section]] mutableCopy];
    [newObject replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:textField.text];

    [self.property1 setObject:newObject forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", indexPath.section]];

}

@end
```

Edit:

I am really more curious about why property1 is changed in VC1 once I modify it in VC2. I did the same thing only with an NSString and assigned the property in VC2 to a local val, but it didn't stick once I went back to VC1. Can this be explained please :(

Comment: could you provide some example code? I'm not quite following what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I haven't looked at the code, but it sounds like you *pass-by-reference* when you want *pass-by-copy*.  This can probably be achieved by setting the `copy` attribute in the `@property`.

Comment: @trojanfoe  Ok thanks for putting the term to the idea, I was thinking there could be some pass by reference going on. Isn't good mvc practice using delegation to pass back?  Should I take advantage of this pass-by-reference, or ignore it/pass by value then use delegation to get the property back to VC1?

Comment: @user3213783 Yeah delegation is the way to go.  The issue with *copy-by-value* on collection types is whether you need to shallow or deep copy, which will depend on what you want to change.  The shallow copy can be done with a `copy` attribute on the `@property` declaration, however a recursive deep copy requires a custom setter/getter method and is a fair amount of work.

Comment: I am really more curious about why property1 is changed in VC1 once I modify it in VC2.  I did the same thing only with an NSString and assigned the property in VC2 to a local val, but it didn't stick once I went back to VC1. Can this be explained please :(

Comment: @user3213783 `NSString` is immutable; try with `NSMutableString` instead.  Long-story-short, you are passing a *reference* to the object so both controllers can update the same object.  This is why you need *copy-by-value*.

Comment: @trojanfoe   I tried with an NSMutableString and it still isn't modified in VC1 when I get back to it.  I'm really confused on why the dictionary contents are changed but the string isn't.

Comment: @user3213783 It probably depends what you do with the string.  Here's a working example using `NSMutableString`: https://gist.github.com/trojanfoe/8535318

Answer (score 0):

Delegate is a kind of style to set VC1 property while in VC2 code area. 
Using block can make your code more clear.
In VC2.h file

```
typedef void(^BeginEditBlock )(NSMutableArray *newObject, int section);

@interface VC2: UITableViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
@property(nonatomic, strong) BeginEditBlock *editBlock;
@end
```

in VC2.m file

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    // Get the cell in which the textfield is embedded
    id textFieldSuper = textField;
    while (![textFieldSuper isKindOfClass:[CustomCel class]]) {
        textFieldSuper = [textFieldSuper superview];
    }
    // Get that cell's index path

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:(CustomCell   *)textFieldSuper];

    NSMutableArray *newObject = [[self.property1 objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", indexPath.section]] mutableCopy];
    [newObject replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:textField.text];

    if(self.editBlock){
        self.editBlock(newObject, indexPath.section);
    }
}
```

in VC1.m file.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"VC2_SEGUE"]){
        VC2 *mVC2 = (VC2 *)segue.destinationViewController;
        mVC2.editBlock = ^(NSMutableArray *newObject, int section){
            [self.property1 setObject:newObject forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", section]];

       };
    }
}
```

About Block description is: [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/Short_Practical_Guide_Blocks/)

Comment: I'd prefer this style to delegates, it makes the coupling really loose.

Comment: Would this be more useful if I need the value in VC1 as SOON as I set it in VC2? Like if VC1 is doing some calculations that are waiting on it being set in VC2? -In the background.

Comment: I think you should read block document I mentioned above first. Block is great style to manage your code. Above code, block is used a property, as soon as VC2 invoke the block, the coding in the block will execute.

Comment: flow wise it does the exact same thing as using a delegate protocol, but without needing to declare a protocol, implement a method, etc.